# Timer for how long button is not pressed

Tags: arduino-uno, c

I would like to timer for how long a button is not pressed. So actually if(buttonState == LOW 'for two seconds') than execute the code that comes after it. But the problem is while the user is still pressing the button the timer already starts.

Code:

```
int ledPin[] = {7,8,9,10};
int ledPin11 = 11;
long randNumber;
const int buttonPin = 2;
int buttonPushCounter = 0;
int buttonState = 0;
int lastButtonState = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 2000;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
 randomSeed(analogRead(0));
 randNumber = random(1, 16);
 Serial.println(randNumber);
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   pinMode(ledPin[i], OUTPUT);
 }
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
 }

 void loop() {
  displayBinary(randNumber); //functie 'display binary'
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval){
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    if(buttonState == LOW){
    antwoord(buttonPushCounter,randNumber);
    delay(5000);
    displayBinary(randNumber);
  }
 }
 buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
 if (buttonState != lastButtonState) { // als de button word ingedrukt krijgt buttonPushCounter + 1
 if (buttonState == HIGH) {
  buttonPushCounter++;
  Serial.print("Nummer hoe vaak is gedrukt");
  Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
 } else {
  Serial.println("off");
}
delay(250);
 }
}

void antwoord(int teller, int antwoord) {
 if (teller == antwoord) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  pinMode(ledPin[i], LOW);
 }
 digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
 delay(250);
 digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
 delay(250);
 digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
 delay(250);
 } else if (teller > antwoord || teller < antwoord) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    pinMode(ledPin[i], LOW);
  }
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  }
}

void displayBinary(byte numToShow) //van byte naar decimaal
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (bitRead(numToShow, i) == 1) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin[i], HIGH);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(ledPin[i], LOW);
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start a timer when the button changes state. Then you timeout if
the button is released **and** it hasn't changed state for too long:

```
void loop()
{
    static int lastButtonState;
    static unsigned long buttonChangeTime;
    int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    unsigned long now = millis();

    // Record time when button changes state.
    if (buttonState != lastButtonState)
        buttonChangeTime = now;

    // Timeout if button is not pushed for too long.
    if (buttonState == LOW && now - buttonChangeTime >= interval)
        Serial.println("Timeout.");

    lastButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

Don't forget to update `lastButtonState` on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough.

I hope I get what you want.

Do while loop about the pressing...

```
if (button == LOW)
     while(!digitalread(button)){};
```

Comment: Why the if? If it's true, the while won't continue, giving basically the same effect :)

Comment: the if here is just if he want to do something before, is just habit.